# Destroying a Rails 3 object in rake?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm stuck on a simple issue here.  I'm building an application that manages a database of coupons, each of which has an expiration date.  I'm trying to build a rake task that will delete the expired coupons.  The relevant code from the rakefile looks like this:

```
desc "Deletes expired offers from the database."
task :purge_expired => :environment do
    today = Date.today.to_s            
    Offer.where('expires_on < ?', today).destroy
end
```

That however fails with the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

I'm just not sure why.  What arguments would be needed?

As an experiment, I found that this worked fine:

```
desc "Deletes expired offers from the database."
task :purge_expired => :environment do
    today = Date.today.to_s            
    puts Offer.where('expires_on < ?', today).count
end
```

That returned the right number of records, so I assume I'm successfully gathering up the right objects.

FWIW, I tried this too, and had no luck:

```
desc "Deletes expired offers from the database."
task :purge_expired => :environment do
    today = Date.today.to_s
    @offers = Offer.where('expires_on < ?', today)
    @offers.destroy
end
```

So I'm kind of out of ideas.  What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks so much for your help.  I'm pretty sure I wouldn't have a job if it weren't for Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just need to use the [`#destroy_all`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-destroy_all) method instead of `#destroy`. The latter requires an id argument.

```
today = Date.today.to_s            
Offer.where('expires_on < ?', today).destroy_all
```

Comment: Worked like a champ, @Rob Davis.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, to help debug things from rake, invoke it with the `--trace` option. Your issue here isn't rake specific though.

The `Offer.where('expires_on < ?', today)` is going to return a collection, and not a single instance of `Offer` and there isn't a `destroy` method available for the collection.

You can iterate over each expired offer and call `destroy`. Something like this:

```
@offers = Offer.where('expires_on < ?', today)
@offers.each { |offer| offer.destroy }
```

Comment: Iterating works, but ActiveRecord::Relation also defines #destroy_all and #delete_all methods.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, @Aaron Hinni. Thanks for clarifying. I'm still new to Rails, and honestly only have kind of a tenuous understanding of the relationship of arrays, collections, and Active Record. I've still got some learning to do!