# Erase records every 60 days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to erase records in my offers models if the record has more that 60 days from the created_at date.

I only found information about how to populate my model with a rake task, but I couldn't find information about how to make a rake task to delete records. So I just wonder if I have to do this with a task or if rails has something else to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create a file for the task:

```
# lib/tasks/delete_old_records.rake
namespace :delete do
  desc 'Delete records older than 60 days'
  task :old_records => :environment do
    Model.where('created_at < ?', 60.days.ago).each do |model|
      model.destroy
    end

    # or Model.delete_all('created_at < ?', 60.days.ago) if you don't need callbacks
  end
end
```

Run with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake delete:old_records
```

Schedule it to run with cron (every day at 8am in this example):

```
0 8 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /my/project/releases/current && RAILS_ENV=production rake delete:old_records 2>&1'
```

You can also use the **whenever** gem to create and manage your crontab on deploys:

```
every 1.day, :at => '8:00 am' do
  rake "delete:old_records"
end
```

Learn more about the gem on [Github](https://github.com/javan/whenever).

Comment: Thanks, I'll going to accept your answer and use the whenever gem as dimuch said on his answer. But I have to wait 4 more minutes to accept yours.

Comment: `...each(&:destroy)` looks prettier :)

Comment: @jdoe It may look prettier, but it's inefficient to put a DB operation in a loop. `where().destroy`, OTOH, *should* generate only one DB query (although I haven't tested to make sure!) and therefore is the proper way of doing this. General rule: DB queries don't belong inside loops; instead, use the power of the DB to make one big query.

Comment: @MarnenLaibow-Koser I don't think `where().destroy` works. `Model.delete_all('created_at > ?', 60.days.ago)` would be the way to do it all in one query, but that skips callbacks. `destroy_all`, doesn't, but then you are loading one record at a time again.

Comment: @Unixmonkey I'd normally use `delete_all` myself, but I didn't specifically recommend it precisely because it skips callbacks (which I've mostly stopped using). But you're right that `where().destroy` doesn't work. The ARel way to do use `delete_all` seems to be `Model.where().delete_all`. I can't find any ARel syntax for `destroy_all`, but `destroy_all(conditions: 'hash')` appears to work. So my advice would now be to use `where().delete_all` if you don't need the callbacks, or `destroy_all` if you do (efficiency is perhaps less important in a cron job).

Comment: It might also possible to use the DB to expire records without invoking the application. I don't know if this is a good idea, though.

Comment: 60.days.ago produces a time stamp Fri, 08 Aug 2014 15:57:18 UTC +00:00. So you'd need to use < in your query instead of > if you want to find older records.

Answer (score 12):

60.days.ago generates a timestamp like

```
Fri, 08 Aug 2014 15:57:18 UTC +00:00
```

So you'd need to use < to look for records older(less) than the timestamp.

```
Online.delete_all("created_at < '#{60.days.ago}'")
```

It's just a slight oversight by Unixmonkey.
I'd also use the delete_all instead of looping each iterating in a block.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [rake task to delete expired offers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310993/destroying-a-rails-3-object-in-rake) , or create class method for your offers model and call it using, for example, [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

Comment: Thanks I'll going to check whenever

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all records older than 60 days in a single query like so:

```
Model.where("created_at < '#{60.days.ago}'").delete_all
```

Comment: `delete_all` won't call any callbacks. Its better to use `destroy_all`