# rails whenever delete records sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

I tried to a records cleanup after certain period of time (6 month) using gem 'whenever'.

In my whenever scheduler :

```
every 1.month, at: '1am' do
  rake 'lib/tasks/cleanup_user.rake'
end
```

In the lib/tasks/cleanup_user.rake

```
@user = User.all.where(:created_at > 'Time.6.month.ago').delete
```

It seems about right. However, I got error 'uninitialized constant User'. I am relatively new in rails. Please assist me.

EDIT : I changed the game by run clean one line command :

```
set :output, "log/cron.log"
    every 1.minutes, :environment => :development do
      command 'User.where("confirmed = 0 AND created_at <= ?", 6.months.ago).delete'
    end
```

I set the specific environment,and run this in command :

```
whenever --set environment=development --update-crontab userscleaning
```

Checking at crontab, its there but still not work. Any thought?

Comment: To confirm, are you: a) deploying via capistrano or b) running the whenever command and updating your crontab?

Comment: I'm running whenever using crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `environment` dependency to your task.

```
task :cleanup_users => :environment do
  User.where(:created_at > 'Time.6.month.ago').delete_all
end
```

If you want the callbacks to trigger, use `destroy_all`

```
task :cleanup_users => :environment do
  User.where(:created_at > 'Time.6.month.ago').destroy_all
end
```

Here is a relevant [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks).

Comment: Hi Hungry coder, I tried that. Its not work too. However, I changed to a cleaner way at above. Hope you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975376/erase-records-every-60-days):

```ruby
# lib/tasks/delete_old_records.rake
namespace :delete do
  desc 'Delete records older than 6 months'
  task old_records: :environment do
    User.where('created_at > ?', 6.month.ago).destroy_all
  end
end
```

Run with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake delete:old_records
```

In whenever:

```ruby
every 1.minutes do
  rake "delete:old_records"
end
```

Or in cron:

```
0 8 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /my/project/releases/current && RAILS_ENV=production rake delete:old_records 2>&1'
```