# object duration ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, duration

How do I set duration for my `Product` object? So that, when a product is created by a user, it sets the JS counter to `1 day` and then destroys/inactivates the `@product` when the clock runs out.

I know how to run this asynchronously, using Sidekiq. The thing is I don't know how to get ruby to work with my working client side JS countdown. And, how to tell Rails that every time a product is created it'd have a period of 1 day (perhaps a callback?).

```
def end_time
  self.destroy in 1.days 
  self.update_attribute(:end_time, Time.now)
end
```

EDIT:

It throws an error for the view.

```
Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it.
```

Here's the model.

```
       #countdown{"data-created-at" => @product.created_at} &nbsp;
                %digits
                    %span.days
                    %pcd DAYS
                %digits
                    %span.hours
                    %pcd HRS
                %digits
                    %span.minutes
                    %pcd MINS
                %digits
                    %span.seconds
                    %pcd SECS
```

products.js

```
   function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

function initializeClock(id, endtime){
  var clock = document.getElementById(id);
  var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
  var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
  var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes'); 
  var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

  function updateClock(){
    var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

    daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

    if(t.total<=0){
      clearInterval(timeInterval);
    }
  }

  updateClock();
  var timeInterval = setInterval(updateClock,1000);
}

var deadline = 'December 15 2015 00:00:50 UTC+0200';
initializeClock('countdown', deadline);
```

Comment: Try to use a scheduler to do this.

Comment: You can use cronjob for deleting record after 1 day. Just set end_time in database and run a background job to check if any product is there which end_time has reached and then delete that product.

Comment: No problem. I know how to run this asynchronously, using Sidekiq. The thing is I don't know how to get ruby to work with my working client side JS countdown. And, how to tell Rails that every time a  product is created it'd have a period of 1 day (perhaps a callback?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, `@product` won't exist after you close the browser - you're probably referring to a `Product` object; which is a different matter.

---

If you wanted to create a `Project` object, and have it time out after a day, you'd be able to use some sort of asynchronous cron system (I'll explain in a second).

However, you are asking something more pertinent:

> The thing is I don't know how to get ruby to work with my working client side JS countdown

You just need to make sure you're able to bind the countdown with the`@product.created_at` attribute:

```
#app/controllers/products_controller.rb
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @product = Product.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/views/products/show.html.erb
<div id="countdown" data-created-at="<%= @product.created_at %>">&nbsp;</div>

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
function getTimeRemaining(endtime){
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.now();
  var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
  var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
  var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
  var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
  return {
    'total': t,
    'days': days,
    'hours': hours,
    'minutes': minutes,
    'seconds': seconds
  };
}

var timeleft = getTimeRemaining($("#countdown").data("created-at"));
$("#countdown").html(timeleft);
```

This should give you the required countdown in JS.

--

In regards the actual removal of a `Product`, you'll have to use one of the scheduling gems, although, really, they are all covers for using a [`cron job`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) - a command called at OS-level.

Cron jobs are invoked on the OS, and they can be used to call any sort of request in any application. With Rails apps, it's best to use a [`rake` task](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake), as follows:

```
#lib/tasks/product_removal.rake
namespace :products do
  desc "Remove
  task :remove => :environment do
     Product.destroy_all('created_at < ?', 1.day.ago)
  end
end
```

This would be accompanied by the appropriate cron job:

```
0 8 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /my/project/releases/current && RAILS_ENV=production rake products:remove 2>&1'
```

Great question about this here:
[Erase records every 60 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975376/erase-records-every-60-days)

Comment: Rich, thanks so much for your answer! A couple of points though, I edited my question with the necessary code for you to review. Putting the cron job aside for now (deleting old records), how do I tell Rails that every time a `Product` object is created it would set the JS countdown duration for 1 day? And, when the clock runs out it would stamp the `end_time` in the products table?