# Delete files in my Rails 3.2 that are stored in the public/data folder after downloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails 3.2 app that you can upload a file then it provides a download link to download the file. I want the app to auto delete the files after a certain number of days/hours after it's been download. So this will clear up space in the app for more downloading. The upload files are going into public/data folder in my app. I have searched and can't seem to find much on this. I believe it my be some kind of script placed in my app but not sure how or where to start. Any help would be cool? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an expert on rake tasks but I definitely know that you need to create a rake task for this one. Hope this is a starting guide into what you are after:

[Erase records every 60 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13975376/erase-records-every-60-days)

[Destroying a Rails 3 object in rake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310993/destroying-a-rails-3-object-in-rake)

You may also want to look at the following Railcasts episode [164 Cron in Ruby](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby). There are a variety of scheduler gems to use.

[Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Hope these resources help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I will check into rake tasks as I'm not to familiar with it. Still in the learning process and trying to learn much as I can.

Comment: kind of seems like what I need but still can't figure out the right coding.